# How to find code coverage of test cases run on chromium for android?

Tags: android, code-coverage, chromium, emma

What are the tools available ? I am working on Ubuntu. I cannot use Visual studio tools. Can I use Emma? If so, How?

EDIT:I am using emma. I was able to generate the coverage.em file using the following command:

```
java -cp ./third_party/android_tools/sdk/tools/lib/emma.jar emma instr -m overwrite -cp out/Release/unit_tests_apk/
```

But the coverage.ec was not generated. Any ideas ? Any other way to generate the code coverage for chromium android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below step will create `.em` files in `out/Release/lib.java` and `.ec` files in the coverage directory mentioned (`out/Release/CoverageDirectory`):

```
build/android/test_runner.py instrumentation --test-apk=ContentShellTest --release -vvv --coverage-dir out/Release/CoverageDirectory
```

The below step will take the coverage directory (containing `.ec` files)   mentioned above and the `out/Release` directory (containing `.em` files generated above) and generate the html coverage report.

```
build/android/generate_emma_html.py --coverage-dir out/Release/CoverageDirectory --metadata-dir out/Release --cleanup --output out/Release/CoverageDirectory/coverage_html/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Include and export emma.jar into the project under test
2. Create ant build ﬁles for both project under test and test  project.
3. Build ’instrument’ target for project under test
4. Build ’debug emma install test’ target for the test project
5. Run tests on emulator
6. Results are found in bin folder of test project

Steps are from my [presentation](http://www.jdays.se/documents/19008/473142/Android+Unit+Testing+-+Jonas+Estberger.pdf/c564ba55-772f-4803-aab6-9dc6ea287718?version=1.0) on jDays last year. I can recommend [Android Application Testing Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/android-application-testing-guide/book) by Diego Torres Milano if you want to read up on Android unit testing.

Comment: I have instrumented the the tests, but I am notable to find the .ec and .em files. I need these two files for generating the HTML file. I used this command : build/android/gyp/emma_instr.py copy --input-path out/Release/unit_tests_apk/ --output-path out/Debug/coverage --coverage-file coverage.em --sources-file coverage.ec